# Python Youtube API v3 Uploading Video with API Key

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, oauth, youtube-data-api

Is it possible to upload videos to Youtube with python through the Youtube v3 API and an API Key?

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload

API_KEY = 'API key'
file ='./path/to/file.mp4'

def upload_file():
    youtube = build('youtube', 'v3', developerKey=API_KEY)
    media_body=MediaFileUpload(file, chunksize=-1, resumable=True)
    body=dict(
        snippet=dict(
            title="test_title",
            description="something random description",
            tags=["soccer", "sports", "funny"],
            categoryId="22"
        ),
        status=dict(
            privacyStatus="private"
        )
    )

    youtube.videos().insert(
        part=",".join(body.keys()),
        body=body,
        media_body=media_body,
    ).execute()

upload_file()
```

With the provided code I receive the following error message:

```
<HttpError 401 when requesting None returned "API keys are not supported by this API. Expected OAuth2 access token or other authentication credentials that assert a principal. See https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication". Details: "[{'message': 'Login Required.', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'required', 'location': 'Authorization', 'locationType': 'header'}]">
```

It should be a server side script, so without any user interaction for login for etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the [Videos insert](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert) method in the documentation. You will find that it states that it requires authorization

[image]

[Authorization](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication) requires that you request permission of the user to access their data. In your case to insert into a users YouTube account you need their permission.

API keys on the other hand are only used to get read only access access public data.  You cant access a private user account with it.

Comment: Is there a way to do the authorization automatically, without any user interaction for my personal account?

Comment: Not with YouTube You will need to authorize it at least once then store the refresh token. Then overtime after that you can use the refresh token to request a new access token and wont have to authorize it again.